# Extract lines from text files using python

Tags: python

I have over 100 .out files, which are output files from a statistical software called MPlus. In each of the files (which can be opened with any text editor), out of several hundred lines of text, there are a couple of lines that I am interested in. The lines look like these ->

```
 I        ON
    K1                -0.247      0.321     -0.769      0.442
    K2                 0.161      0.232      0.696      0.486

 S        ON
    K1                 0.035      0.143      0.247      0.805
    K2                -0.123      0.154     -0.799      0.424

 Q        ON
    K1                 0.083      0.325      0.255      0.798
    K2                 0.039      0.229      0.169      0.866

 I        ON
    LABTOTF1           0.014      0.018      0.787      0.431
    LABTOTG2           0.011      0.017      0.626      0.532
    UGLABTOT           0.001      0.004      0.272      0.786
    UMLABTOT           0.098      0.147      0.664      0.507

 S        ON
    LABTOTF1          -0.008      0.019     -0.406      0.684
    LABTOTF2           0.000      0.013     -0.018      0.986
    UGLABTOT          -0.001      0.003     -0.209      0.835
    UMLABTOT          -0.063      0.115     -0.548      0.584

 Q        ON
    LABTOTF1          -0.013      0.025     -0.532      0.595
    LABTOTF2          -0.014      0.023     -0.596      0.551
    UGLABTOT           0.007      0.006      1.131      0.258
    UMLABTOT          -0.489      0.171     -2.859      0.004
```

The numbers keep changing and the variables (K1, K2, LABTOTF1, etc.), and the number of variables keep changing through the files. But `I        ON`, `S        ON`, `Q        ON` are present in all the files.

I would like to extract these lines from these output files, and throw them into a single output file using a python script.

As of yet, my method includes writing nested for loops which is neither efficient or effective since the number of lines keep changing in each file.

My first terrible 'test' attempt at getting just the line `I        ON` and the values (`K1 & K2`) uses the following lines of code:

```
file = open("./my_folder/my_file.out","r")
lines = [line for line in file]
file.close()
collector = []
for i in range(0,len(lines)):
    if lines[i] == '\n':
        continue
    elif "I        ON\n" in lines[i]:
        collector.append(lines[i])
        collector.append(lines[i+1])
        collector.append(lines[i+2])
        i += 4
        continue
```

What is the most efficient and pythonic way of extracting these lines from a text file?

EDIT: The lines I am interested in are the 'header' as well as the lines which contain the variables+values. For eg. if I wanted the `I        ON` section, I would like to pull the following lines from the previous example:

```
I        ON
    K1                -0.247      0.321     -0.769      0.442
    K2                 0.161      0.232      0.696      0.486
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the file structure:

```
out_lines = []
for line in lines:
    if len(line.strip().split()) == 2:
        out_lines.append(line)
```

Comment: Sorry, looks like I wasn't clear in my question. Updated it to show exactly what lines I'm interested in pulling.

Comment: You could easily expand my example for that. Simply append every line to `out_lines`, and if the condition on the second line (`if len(line.strip().split()) == 2`) is true, "flush" that list of lines and start a new one.

Comment: Hi Shachar, the reason that won't work is because of lack of specificity. If there is another line in the text which had only two words, that will get appended to the output variable  too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions, if you want to search for exact key structures. The code below is for only one '.out' file and produces one file for each heading type of your test data above.

```
import re
file_path = 'E:\\' # the path to the folder with the .out file
file_name = 'test.out'

# for multiple files, insert create a loop for the section below.
with open(file_path + file_name, 'r') as f:
    line_keys = f.readline()
    while line_keys:  # If it is not empty
        key_search = re.search(' ?[ISQ]\s*ON', line_keys)  # search for the key pattern
        if key_search is not None:  # If a match is found
            file_output = line_keys[1:2] + '.txt'
            with open(file_path + file_output, 'a') as f_out:
                f_out.write(line_keys)  # If you repeatedly want the heading of each section
                while True:  # Read the subsequent lines
                    lines_data = f.readline()
                    if lines_data == "\n":
                        break
                    if lines_data == "":
                        break
                    f_out.write(lines_data)
                f_out.write('\n')  # to separate the different sections by a blank line
        line_keys = f.readline()
```